# Integrating out a variable in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, renormalization, eigenvalue

In the lecture https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9G54aCkNH0 (or see https://www.theorie.physik.uni-muenchen.de/activities/schools/archiv/asc_school_14/komargodski_notes.pdf for notes), Zohar Komargodski begins by examining the Hamiltonian
$$H=\frac{1}{2}p_x^2+\frac{1}{2}p_y^2+\frac{1}{2}\lambda^2x^2y^2.$$
He argues that for $|x|\rightarrow\infty$, the $y$ part of the Hamiltonian behaves like a Harmonic oscillator with a very big mass. Therefore, it will settle in its vacuum, which would have energy $E=\frac{1}{2}\lambda|x|$. Then the effective Hamiltonian for the $x$ degree of freedom would be $H=\frac{1}{2}p_x^2+\frac{1}{2}\lambda|x|$, after integrating out the degree of freedom of $y$.

I was wondering what this integrating out means quantum mechanically. To respond to this question I wrote the Hamiltonian in the form
$$H=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2}p_x^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}+n\right)\lambda|x|\right)|n\rangle_y\langle n|_y,$$
In terms of the usual harmonic oscillator eigenfunctions for the $y$ direction. However, I don't know how to argue that at large $|x|$ the only important term is the $n=0$ one.

In a thermodynamical setting I guess this would make sense but at no point in the lecture did he mention a low temperature limit.